# How to configure my docker pypi server to use pypiserver[cache]?

Tags: python, docker, pypiserver

I'm using [docker pypi server](https://hub.docker.com/r/pypiserver/pypiserver) as my internal pip server. I have thousands of requests and sometimes my server fails (i.e. reaches 5 timeouts)

[pypiserver](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/) specifies an option that can help with that: [using cache](https://pypi.org/project/pypiserver/#serving-thousands-of-packages). **How can I make my docker run with this option enabled (OR is there another way to handle the request load better)**?

- The [docker tutorial](https://hub.docker.com/r/pypiserver/pypiserver) specifies a cache-related command : `--cache-control AGE`  but it has nothing to do with the pypi caching I want.
- Here is my docker run command: `sudo docker run -p 80:8080 -v /home/bla/.pypi_server/packages:/data/packages pypiserver/pypiserver:latest`